# Stopword not removing one word

Tags: python, filtering, text-mining

i want to remove 'dan' in filtering process, but didnt work.
here is my code

```
for row in readCSV:
        _word = []
        username = row[0]
        date = row[1]
        text = row[2].lower()
        text = re.sub(r'@[A-Za-z0-9_]+','',text)
        text = re.sub(r'http\S+', '',text)

        text = replaceMultiple(text, ["!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",
                                      ")","_","-","+","=","{","}","[","]",
                                      "\\","/",",",".","?","<",">",":",";",
                                      "'",'"',"~","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"], '')
        text = text.strip()
        nltk_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
        stop_words = set(stopwords.words("indonesian"))
        stop_words_new = ['aku','dan','duh','hhhmmm','thn','nih','tgl',
                          'hai','jazz','bro','broo','msh','']
        new_stopwords_list = stop_words.union(stop_words_new)
```

words in stop_words_new is removed except 'dan'.
why?

Comment: since you can remove all other word it should mean ur code is working. may be look at the csv file (in excel and in python) for example if dan is well encoded when you read your csv

Comment: "didn't work" isn't a description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should not be working because you are joining a set with a list. Try making the stop_words_new a set instead of a list